# Task.Factory.FromAsync syntax in VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have an implementation of Task.Factory.FromAsync in C# that I would like to write in VB.NET.

This is the C# syntax.

```
public static Task<int> SendAsync(this Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(
                       socket.BeginSend(buffer, offset, count, SocketFlags.None, null, socket),
                 socket.EndSend);
}
```

I have converted it to the following in VB.NET

```
Public Shared Function SendAsync(socket As Socket, buffer As Byte(), offset As Integer, count As Integer) As Task(Of Integer)
    Return Task.Factory.FromAsync(Of Integer)(socket.BeginSend(buffer, offset, count, SocketFlags.None, Nothing, socket), socket.EndSend)
End Function
```

However, in the VB.NET syntax, I get the following error. This code worked perfectly in C#.

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'EndSend' accepts this number of arguments.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [`AddressOf` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx):

```
Public Shared Function SendAsync(socket As Socket, buffer As Byte(), offset As Integer, count As Integer) As Task(Of Integer)
    Return Task.Factory.FromAsync(...(...), AddressOf socket.EndSend)
End Function
```

Since you can omit the `()` when calling a method in VB.Net, the compiler does not know that you want to use `socket.EndSend` as a delegate instead of calling it and thus expects it to return a `Func(Of IAsyncResult, Integer)`, which it doesn't do. Hence the overload resolution error.